# Codeeval's new(er) node.js based javascript input system is broken, or I am

Tags: node.js

NOTE: I'm not asking for a solution to a problem - I'm trying to figure out why my solutions aren't being accepted.

Here's their template for submitting a solution:

```
var fs  = require("fs");
fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString().split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
    if (line != "") {
        //do something here
        //console.log(answer_line);
    }
});
```

So, you are supposed to insert your solution, console.log'ing your output.

And here's what is generated as a result, regardless of what output I submit:

```
fs.js:338
   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                  ^
TypeError: path must be a string
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:338:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:182:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<tmp>/source.js:33:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Could someone more knowledgeable in node.js tell me whether codeval is even getting to my code before crashing?

tx.

Comment: Are you sure `process.argv[2]` is what you think it is?

Comment: That's the boiler plate they give you to wrap your code in.

Comment: Be that as it may, it doesn't answer the question.  My guess is `argv[2]` isn't exactly what you're expecting -- maybe there's a blank line in it.  Find out what's getting passed and you'll probably find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're most probably trying to open an input file in a challenge which doesn't provide this input file (i'm a developer at codeeval.com)